# How to display mutiple views on the 2013 SharePoint navigation bar for one Library

Tags: 2013, document-library, navigation, view-styles

I want to use one SharePoint 2013 Library with multiple views and have links to each view on my navigation bar.  I have created different views for the library but how do I lock those views in on my navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding links using Navigation link in Site Settings -> Navigation under Look and Feel Section

Comment: OH my Goodness!  You are AWESOME.  It worked.  I just took the link like you stated from the new view I created and linked it to the navigation settings.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Go to Library for which you created views. Copy the url for different views you created.
If not aware how to capture url below image will help you[image: Image 1]

You can select different views from dropdown and capture urls.

Then you can add them in nevigation as below:
[image: Image 2]